# Saving An Object from Another Object With Different Class Name - IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, object, parse-server

I am trying to save an object with the info retrieved from another object by a query with the code below. I am retrieving the object from class test2 with a query and want to save the object to class test1. However with the code below, when I make itemObj=ob1, the class name of itemObj starts to be test2. How can I carry all the info from ob1 to itemObj while keeping the class name as test1? Is there anyway to do this. I searched the web but couldn't find any similar issue? Thank you.

```
var itemObj = PFObject(className: "test1")
                itemObj = ob1

                itemObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (success) {

                        print("saved", terminator: "")

                    } else {

                        print("error", terminator: "")

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your class `test1` needs a reference to an instance of class `test2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the var itemObj, you created a pfobject with a particular object id. You should not do it. You can either save the ob1 directly or, pass it like this:

```
var itemObj = PFObject(className: "test1")
itemObj["value1"] = ob1["value1"]
itemObj["value2"] = ob1["value2"]          
itemObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {

                    print("saved", terminator: "")

                } else {

                    print("error", terminator: "")

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you Abin, I was looking for an easier way as there were lots of items but I did it in your way finally:)